# Dependent types/Parametric polymorphism in Common Lisp?

Tags: types, macros, common-lisp, dependent-type, parametric-polymorphism

I want to write some generic code dealing with reflection groups, and therefore need to set up some types which reflect mathematical structures (vector space, affine space, ...). As I really want to reflect those structures faithfully in types, I need a way to define some kind of parametric type.

So in particular, I'd want to be able to write the following code

```
(defclass RealVectorSpace ()
  ((V :accessor underlying-set
      :type Set)
   (vector-add :accessor add
               :type (function ((set-as-type V) (set-as-type V)) (set-as-type V)))
   (scalar-mult :accessor s-mult
                :type (function (real (set-as-type V)) (set-as-type V)))
```

which should specify a new type RealVectorSpace which would be given by a triple (V vector-add scalar) where V can be anything, and vector-add is a function taking two parameters of type V (sic) that evaluates to something of type V.

Of course, this type wouldn't be quite a faithful reflection of the concept of a real vector space, because vector-add and scalar-mult would still need to satisfy some further properties. But even turning that 'dream' above into real code eludes me.

**Edit:** In response to sds's answer, let me put forward the following clarification of my original question: in a nutshell, it seems I need to have *dependent types* in Lisp, which is different from asking just for parametric classes. In fact, Haskell has parametric types but does not have (at least it's not built-in in an obvious way) dependent types. The lack of dependent types in Haskell is for instance discussed [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Dependent_type).

**1. Can anyone help me turn my dream into code?**

**2. I've heard somewhere that you don't need parametric classes in Lisp because of Lisp macros. If that's true, can someone explain how you'd use defmacro to implement/fake parametric classes in Common Lisp?**

Comment: Since Common Lisp has no useful type system for that and especially dependent types, it makes very little sense. I propose to use a programming language with an elaborate type system like Haskell or something like Axiom ( http://fricas.github.io/api/VectorSpaceBasis.html ).

Comment: Of course Common Lisp has no useful type system. But the question is, what does "has" mean? For example, even without CLOS you can easily cook up your own OO just through lexical closures.

Comment: if you have a specific question, best with code, then ask. Otherwise I fear a broad speculative question is not the best fit for Stackoverflow, which focuses on real practical programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go: a partial answer/solution to my question (why partial? see below). Many thanks to sds for helping me figure this out!

Let me begin by making a clarification. When I posed my question initially, I used the term 'parametric type' imprecisely, having only a vague definition as 'a type depending parameters' in mind. I basically wanted some gadget allowing me to write the following pseudo-code (in a pseudo-language):

```
class List<T> {
   //implementation
};
l = new List<string>;
l.push("Hello World!");
```

Making sense of the above pseudo-code is pretty straight-forward (see sds's answer). However, ambiguity arises if one starts to wonder whether the expressions `List<T>` and `List` themselves should have a meaning. Indeed, in C++ for example, the expressions would be undefined, for the effect of the template definition

```
template <typename T>
class List {
 public:
   T car;
   List<T> *cdr;
};
```

is as if defining separately, for each type `T`, a type `List<T>`. In contrast, in languages like Java that implement *generic types*, the expression `List<T>` (where `T` is a free variable) makes sense and denotes a type, namely the generic type of a list over *some* type `T`, so that one could e.g. write a polymorphic function like

```
T car(List<T> l) {
 return l.car;
}
```

In short, in C++ we only have the (infinite) collection of all types `List<T>` where `T` runs over all types, whereas in Java this collection itself exists as an object in the language, as the generic type `List<T>`.

**Now to my proposed partial solution**, which I will briefly sketch in words before writing the actual Lisp code. The solution is based on *type families* and the *dependent sum* of such families, i.e. we are going to interpret a parametric type like the type `List<T>` above as a function `List` of one argument whose values are types, and we fake the Java-style generic type `List<T>` as the *dependent sum type* `DepSum(List)`, which simply consists of pairs `(a,b)` where `a` is some type and `b` is of type `List(b)`.

Returning to the example of defining a real vector space over a set `X`, I would like to write something like

```
(defclassfamily RealVectorSpaceOver (X) ()
   ((add :initarg :add
         :reader add
         :type (function (X X) X))
    (s-mult :initarg :s-mult
            :reader s-mult
            :type (function (real X) X)))
```

defining for me a function RealVectorSpaceOver that, given a class `A`, would return a class as if defined manually by

```
(defclass RealVectorSpaceOverA ()
   ((add :initarg :add
         :reader add
         :type (function (A A) A))
    (s-mult :initarg :s-mult
            :reader s-mult
            :type (function (real A) A)))
```

Basically, I could copy-n-paste the solution of sds here, but there are two problems with this. First of all, the result would not be a (side-effect-free) function, for example the form

```
(typep (make-instance (RealVectorSpaceOver A)
                      :add (lambda (x y) nil)
                      :s-mult (lambda (x y) nil))
       (RealVectorSpaceOver A))
```

would evaluate to `nil` because there are two calls to `RealVectorSpaceOver` here, and each call creates a new (and therefore different) class. Thus, we need to wrap this function in some code that caches the result once it has been called for the first time.

The other problem is that using `defclass` to create classes programmatically has the effect of changing the class name space, possibly redefining existing classes. To avoid this, one can instead create new classes directly by instantiating the meta class `standard-class`. For example

```
(make-instance 'standard-class
                 :name (intern "B")
                 :direct-superclasses '(A)
                 :direct-slots '((x :initargs (:x) :readers (x))))
```

is equivalent to

```
(defclass B (A)
       ((x :initarg :x :reader x)))
```

but wouldn't redefine any pre-existing class `B`. Note that the format for the `:direct-slots` argument differs slightly from the `defclass` format for defining slots. Using a helper function `canonicalize-direct-slot-defs` that transforms the latter into the former (taken from the book 'The Art of the Metaobject Protocol'), the macro `defclassfamily` can be implemented as follows:

```
(defmacro defclassfamily (name variables superclasses slot-defs)
  (let ((stripped-variables (strip-variables variables))
        (variable-types (types-of-variables variables))
        (type-decls (type-decls-from-variables variables)))

    `(flet ((f ,stripped-variables
             (make-instance 'standard-class
                             :name (intern (format nil "~S<~S>" ',name (list ,@stripped-variables)))
                             :direct-superclasses ,superclasses 
                             :direct-slots ,(canonicalize-direct-slots slot-defs))))
       (let ((g (cache-function #'f)))
         (defun ,name ,stripped-variables
           ,@type-decls
           (the standard-class (funcall g ,@stripped-variables)))
         (defmethod argument-signature ((x (eql #',name)))
           ',variable-types)))))
```

The above code first defines a function `f` representing the desired type family, then creates a cached-version `g` of it using a helper function `cache-function` (insert your own implementation), and then defines a new function in the name space using `defun`, enforcing the types for the arguments (`defclassfamily` accepts typed arguments similar to `defmethod`, so that `(defclassfamily F ((X Set) Y) ...` would define a family `F` of two parameters, with the first one being of type `Set`) and the return value of the class family. Moreover, there are some simple helper function `strip-variables`, `types-of-variables`, and `type-decls-from-variables` that transform the expression given the variables of the type family (`(X Set) Y` in the previous example). They are defined as follows:

```
(defun strip-variables (specialized-lambda-list)
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
            (if (consp x)
              (car x)
              x))
          specialized-lambda-list))
(defun types-of-variables (var-declarations)
  (mapcar (lambda (var-declaration) (if (consp var-declaration) (second var-declaration) t)) var-declarations))
(defun type-decls-from-variables (var-declarations)
  (mapcar (lambda (var-declaration)
            (if (consp var-declaration)
              `(declare (type ,(second var-declaration) ,(first var-declaration)))
              `(declare (type t ,var-declaration))))
          var-declarations))
```

Finally, we record the types of the arguments taken by our family using a method `argument-signature`, so that

```
(argument-signature (defclassfamily F ((X Set) Y) ... ))
```

would evaluate to `(Set t)`.

**The dependent sum of a type family of one parameter** is implemented by the following code:

```
(defclass DepSum (standard-class)
  ((family :initarg :family :reader family)
   (arg-type :initarg :arg-type :reader arg-type)))
(defmethod make-instance :before ((sum-class DepSum) &key pr1 pr2)
  (assert (and (typep pr1 (arg-type sum-class))
               (typep pr2 (funcall (family sum-class) pr1)))))
(defmethod sb-mop:validate-superclass ((class DepSum) (super-class standard-class))
  t)
(defun depsum (f)
  (let ((arg-type (car (argument-signature f))))
    (make-instance 'DepSum
                   :name (intern (format nil "DepSum_{x:~A} ~A(x)" arg-type f))
                   :direct-superclasses ()
                   :direct-slots `((:name pr1 :initargs (:pr1) :readers (pr1) :type ,arg-type)
                                   (:name pr2 :initargs (:pr2) :readers (pr2)))
                   :direct-slots `((:name pr1 :initargs (:pr1) :readers (pr1)))
                   :family f
                   :arg-type arg-type)))
```

so that we could define a type `RealVectorSpace` using

```
(let ((rvs-type (depsum #'RealVectorSpaceOver)))
  (deftype RealVectorSpace ()
    rvs-type))
```

and write

```
(make-instance (depsum #'RealVectorSpaceOver) :pr1 X :pr2 some-rvs-over-X)
```

to create an object of type `RealVectorSpace`. The above code works by creating a *meta-class* (i.e. subclass of `standard-class`) `DepSum`, which represents the type of all dependent sums and whose instances are dependent sums of specific families. Type safety is enforced by hooking into calls like `(make-instance (depsum #'RealVectorSpaceOver) ...)` via `(defmethod make-instance :before ((sum-class DepSum ...`. Unfortunately, it seems we have to rely on `assert` for this type check (I wasn't able to figure out how to make it work with `declare`).
Lastly, the code `(defmethod sb-mop:validate-superclass ...` is implementation-dependent (for SBCL in this case) and necessary in order to be able to instantiate instances of `DepSum` like `(depsum #'RealVectorSpaceOver)`.

**Why is this only a partial answer?** Because I have not made the vector space axioms part of the type of `RealVectorSpaceOver` (or `RealVectorSpace`). Indeed, such a thing would require to give *an actual proof* of these axioms as part of the datum in a call to `(make-instance (RealVectorSpaceOver X) ...`. Such a thing is certainly possible in fancy languages like Coq, but seems totally out-of-reach in that old, yet lovable mess that is Common Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that what you want makes much sense,
but as an example of macro (ab)use, here you go:

```
(defmacro define-real-vector-space (type &optional name)
  `(defclass ,(or name (intern (format nil "REAL-VECTOR-SPACE-~A" type))) ()
     ((V :reader underlying-set :initform ',type)
      (vector-add :accessor add
                  :type (function ((x ,type) (y ,type)) => ,type))
      (scalar-mult :accessor s-mult
                   :type (function ((x real) (v ,type) => ,type))))))
;; sample underlying set:
(deftype 3d () (array real (3)))
;; use it:
(macroexpand-1 '(define-real-vector-space 3d))
==>
(DEFCLASS REAL-VECTOR-SPACE-3D NIL
 ((V :READER UNDERLYING-SET :INITFORM '|3D|)
  (VECTOR-ADD :ACCESSOR ADD :TYPE (FUNCTION ((X |3D|) (Y |3D|)) => |3D|))
  (SCALAR-MULT :ACCESSOR S-MULT :TYPE #'((X REAL) (V |3D|) => |3D|))))
(define-real-vector-space 3d)
```

Responding to the comment:

If you want a *single* `real-vector-space` class, you are, essentially,
asking for the `vector-add` and `scalar-mult` slots to have type which
depends on the value of the `V` slot.
This would imply that `(setf (underlying-set rvs) some-new-type)` would
have to check that `(add rvs)` and `(s-mult rvs)` have to appropriate
type for `some-new-type`. 
Essentially, this means that either every object of type
`real-vector-space` is immutable, of all slots are modified
simultaneously.
The former option can be accomplished by a judicious use
of [MOP](http://mop.lisp.se/).
I am not sure if the latter is possible in Lisp.

Comment: That's helpful, but not what I want: there should just be one type RealVectorSpace, not a type RealVectorSpaceOverV for every V.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind giving some indications how the MOP could be used to effect what I have in mind? Browsing through the online literature on the meta object protocol didn't help me understand how one could put it to use.

Comment: You would need to add an `after` method to `make-instance` that would do your checking. Please take a look at the docs, play around, and ask a separate question if you hit a block.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about **LIL**, the **Lisp Interface Library**, described in [LIL: CLOS reaches higher-order, sheds identity
and has a transformative experience](https://common-lisp.net/~frideau/lil-ilc2012/lil-ilc2012.pdf) from Faré Rideau. The [github page](https://github.com/fare/lisp-interface-library/) has more details.

Basically, LIL tries to express parametric polymorphism through an additional parameter (the *interface*, which is like a type class) that can be made implicit thanks to dynamic scoping.

On the other hand, what you want to express is really easy to do with OCaml modules, so depending on your needs you may better follow Rainer Joswig's advice (use another language).

```ml
module type VectorSpace =
  functor (S : sig val dimension : int end)
          (F : sig type scalar val zero : scalar end) ->
  sig
    type vector = F.scalar array
    val add : vector -> vector -> vector
    val mul : F.scalar -> vector -> vector
  end
```

As for properties (as requested in comments), you might need to use a more complex type system (Coq?).
An example of how Common Lisp can abstract over things nicely is [Gábor Melis](https://github.com/melisgl)'s [MGL-CUBE](https://melisgl.github.io/mgl-pax-world/cube-manual.html#x-28MGL-CUBE-3A-40CUBE-MANUAL-20MGL-PAX-3ASECTION-29).

Comment: Thx, looks interesting. You say "it's really easy to do with OCaml modules". How would you make the extra properties (vector space axioms) part of the type?

Comment: @BlenderBender Axioms/properties are harder to do, better ask another question for OCaml experts.

Comment: I doubt it would even be possible in OCaml; I clearly wasn't thinking straight when I posed this question.